# How do I mimic browser back arrow in my application page?

Tags: python, html, django

request.path gives me the clicked url.
I need a return link on that page which on clicking, should return to Referrer page,
just as it would happen in case of browser back arrow . I do not maintain any session and 
do not want to hardcode the referrer page url.

Comment: Don't bother. If you try to reinvent the back button, you will do it badly. For instance, in this case, it will go *forwards* to the page that the user came from (if it works at all). If they then click their real back button it will take them back to the page they clicked the back link from.

Comment: I will have to second David. The best you can hope for is the javascript listed in the answers, as the referrer header is sketchy at best (a lot of programs block it, and even if they don't it might be inaccurate).

Comment: Of course the back JS has the same problem. The user clicks a **link**, so they expect the back button to take them back. In sort, having something designed to take the user forward that actually (or doesn't, but claims to) take them back, is just plain confusing.

Answer (score 5):

history.go(-1)

http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/Ecmascript/Quickref/history_go.html

Answer (score 1):

How about trying Javascript instead?

```
 <a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1);">Go back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using Javascript:

```
<span onclick='javascript: history.back()'>Previous page</span>
```